# Width of characters in standard svg font

Tags: svg

I'm generating some simple svg for data visualization and as part of that I need
to render several lines of text. I'm using the simple text/textspan. However when
determining when to break the line, I need to know the width of the string. Note that I am *not* using javascript, these are static svg diagrams. My manual mockups work fine on all three platforms(Mac/Windows 10/Linux) in several different browser. I've been searching, but all attempts to find anything about string widths involves dynamic SVG and javascript. Is there any data anywhere on the character widths of the default fonts? I'm using rather simple svg. I'm using the default transform and coordinate space as well.  Or do I have to write a javascript test page to return the widths?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard font is determined by settings of the renderer. Browsers will use the same font they use for HTML content, set by the user and depending on fonts installed on their system. That means text size will differ for each end user.

There is no way around measuring the text after rendering.

Comment: So if I specify a standard font and size (say Arial 12), can I be reasonably sure the they are roughly the same size? and Can I find the size somewhere?

Comment: Reasonably, maybe. But you still depend on the font being installed on the end user system. Even with a web font, I wouldn't take bets, since different browsers understand different font file formats, and they in turn could implement rendering hints differently. - Size information are part of the font definition, obviously. There are font editors that can inspect them (leaving you with a lot of computation to do), or you render your SVG with a browser or a vector grafics program and inspect the result.

Comment: Thanks. The target for the svg images is only the current members of the department (about 26 people).